# SQLSERVER group by (aggregate column based on other column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table which has 3 columns A, B, C

I want to do a query like this:

```
select A, Max(B), ( C in the row having max B ) from Table group by A.
```

is there a way to do such a query?

Test Data:

```
A    B    C
2    5    3
2    6    1
4    5    1
4    7    9
6    5    0
```

the expected result would be:

```
2    6    1
4    7    9
6    5    0
```

Comment: any test data and desired output??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  A,
            B,
            C,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY B DESC)
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT A, B, C
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: +1 as no join is needed, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select t.*
from   table t
join   (Select A,max(b) B from table group by A) c
on  c.a=t.a
and c.b=a.b
```

Comment: Can you explain how this query works and what it is doing differently from the query in the question?

Comment: Get the max value in derived table and join the derived table a column with table column a for match. now u have both a and max of b . find c where both of them exists